# coroutine inside a for loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, for-loop, game-development

i am trying to instantiate 3 "chunk" Game Objects with a 0.5 second interval between each one, right after my first coroutine "DestroyingTree" ends :

```
public class DestroyTree : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody chunk;
    public Transform TreeEnd;
    public GameObject leaves;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DestroyingTree());
    }
    private IEnumerator DestroyingTree()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        Destroy(gameObject);
        leaves.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
        yield return SpawnChunks();
    }

    private IEnumerator SpawnChunks()
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            yield return Spawner();
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Spawner()
    {
        Rigidbody chunkInstance;
        chunkInstance = Instantiate(chunk, TreeEnd.position, TreeEnd.rotation) as Rigidbody;
        chunkInstance.AddForce(TreeEnd.forward * 100f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    }
}
```

i thought the logic was fine, but for some reason only one instance occurs and not 3.

Answer (score 0):

You call

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

so since this object that is running the coroutine is destroyed the remaining routine will not be executed anymore (it will basically be stuck at the next `yield` instruction).

```
private IEnumerator DestroyingTree()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    Destroy(gameObject); // This object gets destroyed and doesn'T exist anymore in the next frame
    leaves.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play(); // This still happens since it is called within this same frame
    yield return SpawnChunks(); // This still gets called in this frame
}

private IEnumerator SpawnChunks()
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        yield return Spawner(); // The first iteration is still called this frame
    }
}

private IEnumerator Spawner()
{
    Rigidbody chunkInstance;
    chunkInstance = Instantiate(chunk, TreeEnd.position, TreeEnd.rotation) as Rigidbody;
    chunkInstance.AddForce(TreeEnd.forward * 100f); // until here all called in this same frame

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f); // NOW THIS IS STUCK
}
```

To understand this a bit further a Coroutine is an [`IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator) and by default Unity does nothing else but simply calling [`MoveNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext) on it once a frame which basically makes it run everything up until the next `yield` instruction - or in the case it is currently already `yield`ing another `IEnumerator` it bubbles down this `MoveNext` to that `IEnumerator` accordingly.

This basically equals a temporary `Update` method, deep down in the underlying `c++` Unity Engine core the `StartCoroutine` basically is registered for this `GameObject` and right after `Update` is finished it also receives a call to run `MoveNext` on all its registered Coroutines.

In the very first call each of your subsequential `IEnuemrator`s runs until the first `yield` instruction - which in your case is the `WaitForSeconds` in `Spawner`. This now causes all the outer `IEnumerator`s also to "wait" until this returns `false` and allows the `Spawner` to continue.

However, since as mentioned in this very first frame you already destroyed the "mother" `GameObject` that actually is running this Coroutine there will never be a next `MoveNext` call for this most outer `IEnumerator`.

---

Now for solving this there are different options. For instance

- you could instead of destroying or deactivating this object rather only disable all other components (visuals and colliders etc) so the visual and interaction effect is the same - but you still allow the routine to run to end and destroy the object when its done

  Like e.g.

  ```
  private IEnumerator DestroyingTree()
  {
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
      leaves.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();

      // any component that has any influence on the scene visuals and interactions etc
      GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
      GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;

      yield return SpawnChunks();

      Destroy(gameObject);
  }
  ```
- or you could use a more lazy workaround and simply have a dedicated GameObject for executing all your coroutines that never gets destroyed.

  Like e.g.

  ```
  public class CoroutineRunner : MonoBavahiour
  {
      private static CoroutineRunner _instance;

      // using a kind of Singleton pattern with lazy instantiation
      public static CoroutineRunner Instance 
      {
          get
          {
              if(_instance) return _instance;

              _instance = FindFirstObjectByType<CoroutineRunner>();

              if(_instance) return _instance;

              _instance = new GameObject(nameof(CoroutineRunner)).AddComponent<CoroutineRunner>();
              return _instance;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  and then in your script

  ```
  void Start()
  {
      CoroutineRunner.Instance.StartCoroutine(DestroyingTree());
  }
  ```